# non trivial convergent sequence

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, compactness

Let $\beta\omega$ be the Stone-Čech compactification of the natural numbers.
We know that it is compact and Hausdorff, but it has no non-trivial convergent sequence.

Is there an example else to be compact and Hausdorff, but it has no non-trivial convergent sequence ?

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, but any finite space, with the discrete topology has this property...

Comment: A finite discrete space has only eventually constant convergent sequences. But I think you want something more sophisticated.

Comment: I think in a Hausdorff space this is equivalent to each subset being sequentially closed. So the space cannot be sequential if you don't want the discrete topology.